# Importance of Banach fixed point in mathematics

Tags: general-topology, analysis, soft-question, fixed-point-theorems

I know the proof of Banach fixed point theorem in complete metric space and two example of it.

It is useful to prove Picard's theorem on existence and uniqueness of ordinary differential equation. In numerical analysis we apply it to prove convergence of an iteration.

Some more applications I want.

Is it possible to generalise it in a topological space? What is the generalization?

Comment: Fixed-point theory is the mathematical base of the concept of Nash Equilibrium - which has innumerable applications.